# In Red language, how to split a string using split, but also keep the delimiters as nessecary

Tags: red

I want to split a string with the `split`, meanwhile the string contains the string used as delimiter which should not be treated as delimiter. I tried in this way as shown in the following code:

```
>> split {1 + 3 `to-string #"^(60)"`c} "`"
== ["1 + 3 " {to-string #"} {"} "c"] ;;I think it should be ["1 + 3 " {to-string #"^(60)"}"c"]
```

`to-string #"^(60)"` used here is to avoid the appearance of  "``" which would be referred as delimiter, but it fails. It seems that the `^(60)` is evaluated to "```" and then is used as delimiter by `split`.
So, what is the mechanism of the `split` in Red language? And how to split a string meanwhile keeping those delimiters that should not be treated as delimiter.

Comment: If you add a tag to your question which shows which language you are using you are more likely to attract people who can help.

Comment: Thank you for your reminder. I have updated my issue.

Comment: An example of input string and output string both expected and actually gotten would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^(60)` is a so-called *codepoint form* that gets loaded as a `` ` `` character.

```
>> "^(60)"
== "`"
```

If you want to avoid that, you should either escape it manually:

```
>> {1 + 3 `to-string #"^^(60)"` c}
== {1 + 3 `to-string #"^^(60)"` c}
```

Or use raw strings:

```
>> %{1 + 3 `to-string #"^(60)"` c}%
== {1 + 3 `to-string #"^^(60)"` c}
```

`split`ting it afterwards is trivial:

```
>> split %{1 + 3 `to-string #"^(60)"` c}% #"`"
== ["1 + 3 " {to-string #"^^(60)"} " c"]
```

---

In case you want to keep `` ` `` character there, then `split` won't cut it. You need something like Parse:

```
>> string: {1 + 3 `to-string #"`"` c}
== {1 + 3 `to-string #"`"` c}
>> parse string [collect [keep to " `" " `" keep to "` " "` " keep copy match to end]]
== ["1 + 3" {to-string #"`"} "c"]
>> parse string [collect some [keep copy _ to copy match [" `" | "` " | end] match]]
== ["1 + 3" {to-string #"`"} "c"]
```

Comment: @lyl your toolchain is outdated, try to [get](https://www.red-lang.org/p/download.html) the latest, *automated* build (not the stable one). I don't think raw strings are mentioned anywhere (poor documentation is Red's motto, unfortunately); basically it's a string that does not require escaping of any special characters within it, they are all treated as-is in their raw form (hence the name). The syntax is `%...{...}...%` where number of `%` on both sides should match (in case the string itself contains `%` character).

Comment: Many thanks. And I updated my last comment. Would you have a look at it?

Comment: I copied your code %{1 + 3 `to-string #"^(60)"` c}% and run it, then get a wrong message `*** Script Error: % operator is missing an argument`. Why? And where can I find detail description about "raw strings"? Escape "^(60)" with an extra "^" i.e. "^^(60), then it can't return to "`" as shown in this example: rejoin split {a`b`c^^(60)d} "`". This will get "abc^^(60)d" not "abc`d". Would you help me with this? Thank you.